# can't get "text" field from nestjs-telegraf context message

Tags: bots, nestjs, telegram, telegraf

I'm writing a telegram's bot using nestjs-telegraf wrapper. I want to get message text sent by telegram. This is my handler:

```
  @On('text')
  async onText(@Ctx() ctx: Context) {
    const msg = ctx.message;
    const update = ctx.update;
    const from = msg.from;
    const chat = msg.chat;
    const date = msg.date;
    // **const text = msg.text;**

    // this.logger.debug('Context - ' + JSON.stringify(ctx));
    this.logger.debug('update - ' + JSON.stringify(update));
    this.logger.debug('text message - ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
    this.logger.debug(`message id ${msg.message_id}`);
    this.logger.debug(`from id ${from.id}`);
    this.logger.debug('from ' + JSON.stringify(from));
    this.logger.debug('chat ' + JSON.stringify(chat));
    this.logger.debug('date ' + JSON.stringify(date));
    // **this.logger.debug('text ' + JSON.stringify(text));**

    ctx.reply('You send ' + msg);
  }
```

If I try to build the code removing the comment on line

```
const text = msg.text;
```

I got the error: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'New & NonChannel & Message.
[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN38k.png)

But, if I run the code with the line commented everithing works and I got this log:

```
[Nest] 148003  - 31/05/2022, 12:36:28   DEBUG [BotService] text message - {"message_id":361,"from":{...},"chat":{..."},"date":1653992754,"text":"this is a message text"}
```

where the text property exists and contains the data I sent from telegram. Enough If I run code in debug mode, I can see the object with the text property filled correctly. Can anyone give me some soggest to compile the code and extract the text?

Thanks

[running code in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYCtw.png)

Comment: couple of solutions are available on this issue: https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/1388

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@WizardStep(1)
  async password(
    @Ctx() ctx: Scenes.WizardContext & SessionContext,
    @Message('text') msg: string,
  ) {
    const isEmail = await this.checkEmail(msg);

    if (!isEmail) {
      await ctx.reply('Введенная почта некорректна, попробуйте еще раз');
      return;
    }

    ctx.session.email = msg;
    await ctx.reply('Введите пароль:');
    ctx.wizard.next();
  }
```

Just  add `@Message('text) msg: string` to params.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [discussion](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/1388), typescript is trying to tell you that not every message coming from a user is a text message. Even if you are listening only 'text' updates, Context must be narrowed to specific message types you are waiting for.

This workaround worked for me:

If I'm waiting for text message

```js
@Hears('hello')
  async sayHello(@Ctx() ctx: CustomContext & { message: Message.TextMessage }) {}
```

If I am waiting for example location

```js
@On('location')
  async locate(
    @Ctx() ctx: CustomContext & { message: Message.LocationMessage },
  ) {}
```

if mixed

```js
@Ctx() ctx: CustomContext & { message: Message.LocationMessage & Message.TextMessage}
```

You can you `Context` instead of `CustomContext`. It is my created custom context with a typed session store.
You can check out this [article](https://medium.com/@sylneyshii/telegraf-guide-e53cdc4e625b) or Telegraf [repo](https://github.com/feathers-studio/telegraf-docs/tree/master/examples) with examples to find out more